# Xcode 7 beta - font rendering crash

Tags: xcode, ios9, xcode7-beta2

Apple have kindly changed the fonts and font size in iOS 9.

I have noticed many of my fixed sized labels are now being truncated(!) which is not good.  I am also getting this crash:

[image: I'm getting this crash in Xcode 7 beta]

The error can be continued and the app will run normally, but obviously something isn't happy.  There is no output to the console, or anything to help debug this apart from

> libFontParser.dylib`TFileDescriptorContext::TFileDescriptorContext:

Answer (score -2):

Search your XIB or storyboard for `customFonts`. Remove it, if it exists, and try again.

Comment: "exist" , not "exit" , sorry